# assign values by ordering

Tags: r, dataframe

my stupid problem is the following:
take the df

```
df = data.frame(a= c(10,100,1,1000,1,1000), b = c(15,5,10,20,5,5))
```

that is

```
         a  b
    1   10 15
    2  100  5
    3    1 10
    4 1000 20
    5    1  5
    6 1000  5
```

now, i would like to assign to a-column new values with the following rationale:

```
         a new_value
    1    1         1
    2    1         1
    3   10         2
    4  100         3
    5 1000         4
    6 1000         4
```

that is, renumber them by their order, but uniquely (i mean, i do *not* want something like

```
         a new_value
    1    1         1
    2    1         2
    3   10         3
    4  100         4
    5 1000         5
    6 1000         6
```

).

the problem is that i cannot do, e.g.

```
unique(df$a[order(df$a)]) = c(1:length(
    unique(df$a[order(df$a)]))
```

The same thing for the b-column.
Moreover, since my actual dataframe is pretty big (~800 MB) i am searching for the smartest (and fastest) way to do this.
I was thinking about some analogous to python dictionary, but i am not sure whether it is the right way to pursue

I am sure you guys have the right answer, it shouldn't be that complicated

just to be clear, the final result should be

```
         a  b new.a new.b
    1   10 15     2     3
    2  100  5     3     1
    3    1 10     1     2
    4 1000 20     4     4
    5    1  5     1     1
    6 1000  5     4     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `order` by 'a', create the 'newvalue' as `.GRP` after grouping by 'a', then assign (`:=`) the 'b' to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(a), newvalue := .GRP, by = a][order(a)][, b:= NULL][]
```

Or

```
setorder(setDT(df), a)[, newvalue :=.GRP ,a][, b:= NULL][]
#      a newvalue
#1:    1        1
#2:    1        1
#3:   10        2
#4:  100        3
#5: 1000        4
#6: 1000        4
```

#### Update

Based on the update in the OP's post

```
setDT(df)[order(a), new.a := .GRP , by = a][order(b), new.b := .GRP, b]
df
#      a  b new.a new.b
#1:   10 15     2     3
#2:  100  5     3     1
#3:    1 10     1     2
#4: 1000 20     4     4
#5:    1  5     1     1
#6: 1000  5     4     1
```

The above can be automated with a loop.

```
 setDT(df)
 nm1 <- names(df)
 for(j in seq_along(df)){
    df[order(eval(as.name(nm1[j]))), paste0("new.", names(df)[j]) := .GRP, by = c(nm1[j])][]
 }
```

Comment: mm, i am not sure this is answering my question: i do not need to reorder the column, i just want to rename corresponding to that ordering